# Definition of a function that does nothing

Tags: python

I need to define a function depending on a condition, so that it either does something or nothing.

e.g.

```
# Code block that *defines* bar
if condition:
  bar = do_stuff
else:
  bar = # ?
# End of the definition of bar

bar()
```

`do_stuff` is a function defined somewhere else that does some useful computation. I want `bar()` to do be defined to do nothing if the condition above is not met. Any ideas?

**Note:** I designed the **if-else** block above for illustration purposes. I know that I could just call `do_stuff()` in the `if` body and `pass` in the `else` body. The code above is just to illustrate a code block after which I need `bar` to be defined either to do something or to do nothing. The block **just defines** the function and is not meant to call it.

Comment: Simply leave off the `else:` clause entirely - or put a `pass` statement in it.

Comment: @TimPeters: It looks like he wants to assign one function or another to `bar`, so he has to assign the name to something to avoid a NameError later.

Comment: @TimPeters Did you read my **Note**?

Comment: @Josh, you wrote your note after I wrote my comment ;-)  With respect to all the suggestions you've gotten, you need to define your "do nothing" function to accept the same arguments as `do_stuff`.  If `bar` takes no arguments, then `bar = lambda: None` is fine.  Else you need something like `bar = lambda *args: None`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set the variable `bar` to be a function that does nothing, there are two options:

- Using a `lambda`:

  ```
  bar = lambda: None
  ```
- Using a function definition:

  ```
  def bar():
      pass
  ```

You could also use `return None` instead of `pass` for the function definition, the behavior is equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a function that does nothing with:

```
def func():
    pass
```

Comment: Since we don't know what the args of `do_stuff` are, you might want to `def func(*args, **kwargs)` instead. Then again, you might not. :)